# Run box shortcut for System Restore

Tags: shortcuts, run-dialog

If you open up the Run dialog box, you can type **`cmd`** for the command prompt, and **`msconfig`** for the configuration utility. What's the equivalent for **System Restore**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> rstrui.exe

As documented [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120915134204/http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Start-System-Restore-from-a-command-prompt).

If you want to run this command from within Safe Mode, start the computer in Safe Mode, login with an account with **Admin** privileges, and then type the following command in the command prompt/run dialog box:

> %systemroot%\system32\restore\rstrui.exe

For more information, go [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20121001144301/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304449) for Microsoft's instructions.